# Как прописать расширенный интерфейс в унаследованном классе. в TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

```
// допустим у меня есть базовый класс у которого есть поле неопределенного типа T
abstract class Base<T> {
    public prop: T;
}

// дальше я создаю некий интерфейс у которого будет 2 поля:
// id - пока не известный тип. допустим может быть number, или string
// name - всегда строка
interface ISmall<T> {
    id: T;
    name: string;
}

// дальше я наследую от базового класса Base и указываю что 
// prop будет типа ISmall, но поле id пока не известно
class Small<T> extends Base<ISmall<T>> {

}

// и тут я создаю 2 экземпляра, где указываю какого типа будет id
let small1: Small<number> = new Small<number>();
let small2: Small<string> = new Small<string>();

// здесь я с легкостью добираюсь до полей и записываю в переменные
let numId: number = small1.prop.id;
let strId: string = small2.prop.id;
let name: string = small2.prop.name;

// теперь я хочу создать еще один класс унаследовавшись от класса Small
// но с одной оговоркой, я хочу к интерфейсу ISmall
// добавить еще одно поле description
interface IBig<T> extends ISmall<T> {
    description: string;
}

// и теперь вот вопрос, как мне прописать заэкстенденный
// интерфейс IBig вот сюда:
class Big<T> extends Small<T> {

}

// создаем экземпляр
let big: Big<string> = new Big<string>();

// здесь по понятным причинам в переменную не запишет
// потмоу что description в prop класса Big нет
let desc: string = big.prop.description;
```

Answer (score 0):

### В вашем случае достаточно этого:

```
class Big<T> extends Small<T> {
    prop: IBig<T>
}
```

### Только на классах:

```
abstract class Base {
    prop: any
}

class Small<T> extends Base {
    prop: {
        id: T;
        name: string;
    }
}

class Big<T> extends Small<T> {
    prop: Small<T>['prop'] & {
        description: string;
    }
}
```

### На интерфейсах:

```
interface Base {
    prop: any;
}
abstract class Base implements Base { }

interface Small<T> {
    prop: {
        id: T;
        name: string;
    }
}
class Small<T> extends Base { }

interface Big<T> extends Small<T> {
    prop: Small<T>['prop'] & {
        description: string;
    }
}
class Big<T> extends Small<T> { }
```

### Как бы написал я:

```
abstract class Base {
    prop: any
}

class Small<T> extends Base {
    prop: Small.$prop<T>
}
namespace Small {
    export interface $prop<T> {
        id: T;
        name: string;
    }
    // export type $prop<T> = {
    //     id: T;
    //     name: string;
    // }
}

class Big<T> extends Small<T> {
    prop: Big.$prop<T>
}
namespace Big {
    export interface $prop<T> extends Small.$prop<T> {
        description: string;
    }
    // export type $prop<T> = Small.$prop<T> & {
    //     description: string;
    // }
}
```

### доки

- declaration merging - http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts